# Change tint color of button based on state in Interface Builder

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder

In Xcode's Interface Builder, I know you can change a button's styling based on its state, but it doesn't seem to apply to the button's tint.

Is it possible to change the tint color of a button based on a specific state?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using `tintColor` to set the text color of the button, you can set the text color property for each state in IB.

UPDATE:
Per documentation here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton

"When configuring a button either programmatically or in Interface Builder, you specify attributes for each state separately. In Interface Builder, use the State Config control in the Attributes inspector to choose the appropriate state and then configure the other attributes"

Tint color is an property that lives outside of the buttons state, as it is inherited from UIView, therefore it is not attributed to any state. State is also a readonly property, so a property observer won't work either.

TLDR: You will need a separate image attributed to the specific state you want, tintColor is applied to all states.

Comment: It's for the button's image.